# Copypasteable console output with html/css/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm writing a tutorial that contains shell commands and their output. The intention is that the text not only **looks like a (linux) console** but that that **readers are able to copy-paste commands** from it.

For this the text must **wrap like a real console**: So no word breaking but no extra newline characters either. Just start a new line when the previous gets full.

**EDIT: also, consecutive spaces must not be trimmed, so a line may have multiple spaces anywhere, and even they must be rendered correctly**

See for example the beginning of http://iwant.sourceforge.net/ext-libs-in-wsdef.html

The command there is longer than the line so it wraps. But there is no newline character in the end of the first line.

I tried several tricks but none worked. The browser would either wrap at word boundaries or not at all. Or then I'd need to add newline chracters or divs, yielding incorrect content when copy-pasting (extra newlines). Non-breaking space (nbsp) didn't help either: they don't (big surprise) break at all.

The only solution I could think of was an ugly hack: I inserted empty img elements between characters. But, as is true for many ugly hacks, it only worked temporarily: at least with the current chrome versions it still renders correctly but if you copy-paste text to a console, it will contain some crap characters representing the img elements.

So is there some "let's break line without really being a newline character" element in HTML? Or a zero-width "breaking space" character between characters could do the trick, but I haven't found such a chracter or element. Or is there a console-like wrap mode in CSS?

Or do I need to use javascript to manipulate the selection programmatically?

Comment: Maybe just add some additional "&nbsp; ( a spacetab ) in your Text. This should do the Job, even if it's not a very clean way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is there a console-like wrap mode in CSS?**

Yes. What you need is `word-break: break-all;`. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break), `break-all` means: "Word breaks may be inserted between any character for non-CJK (Chinese/Japanese/Korean) text.", which is perfect for console output.

EDIT: To display consecutive spaces, you can use `<pre>` instead of `<span>`, define its `white-space` as `pre-wrap`, and `display` as `inline`.

EDIT2: To prevent the beginning spaces from trimmed, you can insert a `<span>` before the `<pre>`, and hide it with 0 width. Actually, I find it is better to use `<samp>` and `<kdb>`, which is semantically more accurate. The fiddle is updated.

EDIT3: @Ville Oikarinen find a way to implement without additional HTML `<span>` element, please check his answer.

A [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cshao/kechr2vf/6/) is made for your example in http://iwant.sourceforge.net/ext-libs-in-wsdef.html please check if you need.

The code would be:

```
<samp><span class="mark"></span>
<kbd class="cmd">
$EDITOR "as-iwant-tutorial-developer/i-have/wsdefdef/src/main/ja      va/com/example/wsdefdef/IwantTutorialWorkspaceProvider.java"
</kbd>
</samp>

.mark {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.cmd {
  color: white;
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution looks promising. Unfortunately I forgot to mention one more requirement (I was working on this problem so long ago), sorry about that. This solution alone won't solve the problem of multiple spaces anywhere on the line. (I edited the question.)

Comment: I remember using nbsp for spaces, but there the problem was breaking: they don't break. If only there was a breaking-space element...

Comment: @VilleOikarinen To display consecutive spaces, you can use `<pre>` instead of `<span>`, I'll edit my answer and update the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks, it's getting closer. But still it seems that spaces in the beginning of the line are trimmed.

Comment: @VilleOikarinen The beginning spaces can be prevented from trimmed by inserting a `span` before console output text. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Wow, now it really starts to look promising. I'll need to update my tool and verify test results of all cornercases. I'll be back.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @shaochuancs your answer was really helpful and I marked it as accepted.

I found out that the empty span of class "mark" wasn't even needed. Here's the edited version I took into use: http://jsfiddle.net/wipu/s4xve6mo/1

```
<div class="console"><samp>
<kbd class="shell prompt">~/iwant-tutorial $ </kbd>
<kbd class="shell cmd">  long-command "as-iwant-tutorial-developer/i-have/wsdefdef/src/main/java/com/example/wsdefdef/IwantTutorialWorkspaceProvider.java"  </kbd><br/>
<kbd class="shell output">  output line 1  </kbd><br/>
<kbd class="shell output">  output line 2 with a loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong word  </kbd><br/>
</samp></div>

.console {
  background: black;
  font-family: monospace;
  width: 60em;
}
.shell {
  word-break: break-all; white-space:pre-wrap; display:inline;
}
.prompt {
  font-weight: bold; color: green;
}
.cmd {
  color: white;
}
.output {
  color: gray;  
}
```

This is the commit that implements it in my document-generator "descript": https://sourceforge.net/p/descript/code/21/

Comment: You are welcome. Implementation without additional HTML `mark` element is definitely more elegant. I'll edit my answer to include this information.